# Cross Domain Iframe Access For Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, mozilla, html5-history

I would like to access a child iframe (iframe2) from a site having a URL suppose **"http://example.com"** . I have this HTML format,

```
<html>
    <body>
    <iframe id="iframe1" src="https://example.com">
       <iframe id="iframe2" src="https://example.com/page1">
       </iframe>
    </iframe>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But i am facing an error in the form of exception

> "Permission denied to access property XXXXXX"

When I used `iframe.contentWindow.document`.

I would like to access the content of `iframe2`. I am facing this problem in Firefox, I fixed this issue in Google Chrome using `window.history.pushstate`, which is a HTML5 API. But somehow the same code is not working in Firefox

I tried a lot many things but still not got any lead on it. Please help !! Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Because the security model is the same as web content, you may need to set `document.domain` to the top level domain for that to work.

Comment: `window.history.pushstate` WORKS in Firefox, but you have a typo, it's `window.history.pushState`. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Thanks for the answer. But i am not able to set document.domain because of the "Permission denied" (Same origin policy) error in the console.